# Magento setStockStatusChangedAutomaticallyFlag: what does it do?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

What does the method `setStockStatusChangedAutomaticallyFlag` do in Magento?
I've done some digging in the source code and I can't quite work out what it does

Comment: When a order is canceled, then that quantity is again added to stock inventory of that product. This is actual check, whether you want inventory back or not.

Answer (score 1):

As a product is purchased on magento site and if the inventory is set, that is decreased by the amount the product is purchased, moreover if the order is cancelled the product quantity is increased again.

This is done by :

```
$product->setStockData($stockData);
```

after a successful order.

Although whether to do above process or not is defined by a flag "setStockStatusChangedAutomatically" if Yes it works as above else not.